# How to completely solve this CodeEval challlenge?

Tags: python, string

The challenge is [here](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/167/)

I am struggling with this for very long time. I don't know what's wrong with my code. I can see output and even check every output of them.

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    test = test.rstrip()
    print test + "1"
    if len(test) > 55:
        test = test[0:40]
        if " " in test:
            lst = test.split(" ")
            lst = lst[0:(len(lst)-1)]
            s = " ".join(lst)
            print s + "...<Read More>"
        else:
            print test + "...<Read More>"
    else:
        print test
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what, if anything, you're asking? This isn't a code-writing service, and if you want help fixing an error *tell us what it is*.

Comment: always helps to visit here too - http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Why are you using `print test + "1"` here? That would certainly throw the CodeEval checker.

Comment: Other than that, you are only missing a space between `...` and `<Read More>`. And the code could be a hell of a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct; the only real error (apart from printing each test case with `'1'` appended) is that you did not reproduce the required output faithfully.

From the description:

> Add a string `‘... <Read More>’` to the end of the resulting string and print it.

You are adding `'...<Read More>'` instead, note the spacing.

Rather than split on all spaces, just use `str.rsplit(' ', 1)` to split just the once, and select the first result of that. That has the advantage you don't even need to test for a space anymore, as strings without spaces result in the whole string being returned as the only result in the list:

```
>>> 'foo bar baz'.rsplit(' ', 1)
['foo bar', 'baz']
>>> 'foo bar baz'.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
'foo bar'
>>> 'foobarbaz'.rsplit(' ', 1)
['foobarbaz']
>>> 'foobarbaz'.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
'foobarbaz'
```

You could also bail out early; if the text is shorter than or equal to 55 characters, print then and use `continue` to move on. This makes your code more readable:

```
for test in test_cases:
    test = test.rstrip()
    if len(test) <= 55:
        print test
        continue

    print test[:40].rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + '... <Read More>'
```

or you could just replace `test` and print just once:

```
for test in test_cases:
    test = test.rstrip()
    if len(test) > 55:
        test = test[:40].rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + '... <Read More>'

    print test
```

Demo:

```
>>> test_cases = '''\
... Tom exhibited.
... Amy Lawrence was proud and glad, and she tried to make Tom see it in her face - but he wouldn't look.
... Tom was tugging at a button-hole and looking sheepish.
... Two thousand verses is a great many - very, very great many.
... Tom's mouth watered for the apple, but he stuck to his work.'''.splitlines(True)
>>> for test in test_cases:
...     test = test.rstrip()
...     if len(test) > 55:
...         test = test[:40].rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + '... <Read More>'
...     print test
... 
Tom exhibited.
Amy Lawrence was proud and glad, and... <Read More>
Tom was tugging at a button-hole and looking sheepish.
Two thousand verses is a great many -... <Read More>
Tom's mouth watered for the apple, but... <Read More>
```

My own version (Python 2 and 3 compatible) passed, in any case.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I forgot to remove print test + "1", which I used to see my output. Thank you! I think the problem is the spacing between "..." and "<Read More>". I should be more careful. Your instructions are really straightforward and educational. I didn't know the second argument of rsplit() before. Thank you very much!